From sqlcli connection string to SQL developer JBC connection
I am running Oracle on a docker container and I'm connected in SQLCL in docker with the following string:
conn sys/Oracle_2023@host.docker.internal:1521/freepdb1 as sysdba


Moreover when I try this on SQLDeveloper with the JBC String jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.docker.internal:1521/freepdb1, as on the image below, I have an error. So I assume my JBC string is wrong. Using Password as Oracle_2023 and username as sys. Any idea how can I connect to SQL Developer?


Sqlcl is running on the host, just like sqldev?

Sqlc (from here https://github.com/marcelo-ochoa/sqlcl-docker-extension) is running on the host yes. It's a docker extension and I am running all in my local machine

Right, so SQLcl is running within the Docker host - even if you instigate it from outside via the extension - and SQL Developer is running outside? You haven't shown the full error but if the host name is being resolved and trying to connect to the Docker host then you may just need to open port 1521 on the firewall to allow that connection in?

Yes, SQLcl is running within the Docker host and SQL Developer is running outside. Firewall in port 1521 is open :) So don't i need to have user and password on jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.docker.internal:1521/freepdb1?

The full error in SQL developer is: "the network adapter could not establish the connection oracle sql developer"

No, the URL should work like that. (You could also use a basic connection with the same host/port/service). The error means it can't reach port 1521 on that host. If you're sure the firewall is open, maybe check the host resolves to the right IP. I don't use Docker so not sure how it maps network traffic through.
